# overflow-y scroll and overflow hidden issue in pop-up window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem, and I cant find solution for that..
I have pop-up window, positioning fixed and 100% height and width.
I want to set  overflow-y: scroll to block `.item-details`, if there be much content - user can scroll, but only that block `.item-details`.

I have already set that

```
.item-details {
border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
padding-top: 38px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

but it dont work..

Here is [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dN9RJ/), thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a height attribute on `.item-details`

Is this what you're after?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dN9RJ/1/)